# Dual boot error with Windows 10 and Kali Linux

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux

I have a Windows 10 Toshiba laptop and I want to dual boot with Kali Linux.

I have reached the point where you divide the partition, I used disk management to partition the free disk space, yet while in the installer the free space shows up as unusable.

[image: Disk Management Photo!]

Comment: @OP: can you shouw the output from disk management?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like windows may of formatted the 'free' space into some kind of usable partition.

If you're *sure* the space the installer is seeing, is the free space that you've separated then I'd just be looking for some kind of delete option in the installer.

Comment: Is there a way to  reformat it to a usable partition for linux.

Comment: There is, but why format it at all? Let the Kali installer format it. Just having some free space is enough.

Comment: @Hennes, this is exactly what I meant. I presume that windows 10 either automatically formatted the space that was split off, or offered to and the user accepted. While installing onto ntfs (I presume that's what windows 10 is natively using) is possible, I very much doubt it's reccomended!.

The user doesn't detail what exactly they've used to shrink the partition but I've noticed that the Kali Linux wiki details using the Kali Linux live installer to do this, so it definately has access to gparted (or other tools to format) to be able to change it to ext3/4/other FS as required.

Comment: I shrinked E:\ with disk management according to this website http://techlog360.com/2015/09/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-v2-0-with-windows-10/                                  But with kali linux installer it says that the empty space is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer i think i had the same problem and this is a little bit over my head so i may say some stuff wrong anyway i have already installed Kali Linux onto the unalocated free space but when i went back into windows it still said unalocated (i know i am spelling it wrong whatever) so i clicked on the unalocated box and went up to click on the refresh option at the top of the window and that fixed it bye!

Comment: Please edit your answer eliminating the fact of it being a single sentence - divide it into paragraphs.